# Как сформировать html-ссылку для Viber?

Tags: html, viber, viber-api

Устанавливаю на сайт кнопку (html-ссылка) для запуска чата в Viber:

Вариант №1

```
<a href="viber://chat?number=+387771234567"><i class="fab fa-viber"></i>Viber</a>
```

Если нажать на ссылку `viber://chat?number=+` за компьютером, запускается приложение viber и открывается диалог с владельцем номера телефона. Проблема: нажатие на эту ссылку не перехватывается приложением viber, установленным на смартфоне.

Вариант №2

```
<a href="viber://add?number=387771234567"><i class="fab fa-viber"></i>Viber</a>
```

Если нажать на ссылку `viber://add?number=` (символа **+** нет в строке ссылки), приложение на смартфоне отрабатывает добавление контакта (запуск чата - отдельное действие пользователя, которое ему ещё нужно совершить самостоятельно), но эта ссылка некорректно перехватывается приложением, установленным на десктопе, которое выдаёт ошибку "действие не может быть выполнено".

Технически решением является проверка устройства через HTTP_USER_AGENT и формирование строки для html-ссылки в зависимости от этого.

Прошу подсказать, правильный ли это путь, или существует универсальное решение создания и обработки ссылки для смартфона и десктопа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставьте вместо плюса `+` код символа url `%2b`.